# Removing Push.ALL in Bluemix Push Notification

Tags: java, push-notification, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I am going to write an Android push notification program and I want to use the tag-based subscription.

After I unsubscribe the default Push.ALL tag and subscribe another self-defined tag, I find that I cannot send the push notification from Bluemix (I just do it manually. I haven't set up a REST API). The error message is:

> Internal server error. No devices found.

I am sure that I have registered the device as I can find my subscription records in Tags page of Bluemix. Before unsubscribing from the Push.ALL tag, I am able to send as well as receive the message.

How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the [Push Notifications REST API Swagger](https://mobile.ng.bluemix.net/imfpushrestapidocs/#/devices) doc to make sure you do have devices registered against your service. I would use the /devices api to accomplish this:

[image]

If there are no devices registered to your Push Notification service you will be shown the error: "Internal server error. No devices found". I would also not recommend unsubscribing the devices from the Push.ALL tag as this is a default tag in the Push service.

Comment: I would like to create an application that only receive the subscribed tags. If I do not unsubscribe Push.ALL tag, how can I do so that I can perform the function? Also, I found that there are devices in REST API but "Internal server error. No devices found" is still shown in my send push page.

Comment: How did you solve your issue? It would be good to know so that others that may experience the issue can see your solution.